# Second-order ODE with substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m struggling with this question:

> Use the substitution $y(t) = z(t)\,e^{-t}$ to transform the ordinary differential equation
>   $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + 2\,\frac{dy}{dt} + y = t^2 e^{-t}$$
>   into an ordinary differential equation for $z(t)$. Hence obtain the general solution for $y(t)$. What is the specific solution which satisfies the initial conditions, $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 0$?

I have an exam in two hours, and I can’t get around this question.

So far I managed to get the first order and second order differentials for $z(t)$, and found that $z''(t) = t^2$, but I don’t know what to do next.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please don't shout and especially not in the subject line.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v= \frac{dz}{dt}$. Then $\frac{dv}{dt}=t^2$ and $ v = \frac{t^3}{3} + c.$

Substituting for $v$, $\frac{dz}{dt} = t^3/3 + c$ so $z(t)=t^4/12 + ct + d$.

Comment: doesn't the integral of v = t^4/12 + ct + d

Comment: Ah yes, I made a mistake in a hurry! Thanks Luke, I'll correct it...